# Read content of server files in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

My task is to generate a report based on content in server files(ascii) in pentaho.

I could come up with job to establish connection, get required files onto disk and generate report. But I want to change the flow by getting files or file content into memory rather than onto disk.

Established connection with server with job entry 'Get a file with SFTP' and file content is injected into transformation which starts with entry 'modified javascript value' .

Could someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in an FTP, or any file system that VFS can access (see [VFS Supported Systems](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html)), you can access these files through the Get File Names Transformation Step, by passing the Filename atribute directly into the input step you use (Text file or XML or any other)